# Individual-wire IDC identification

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to identify the type of connector below.  It's an insulation-displacement type, but clearly not for ribbon cable.  I used these many years ago and also realize there's a special "push" tool.

Googling IDC, single-row, etc. in various ways turns up nothing but ribbon-cable type.

Can someone ID the type of connector (by specific name or manufacturer/pn) and the tool?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used connectors like that back in the mid 80s, we called them 'Panduit' connectors because that was the brand. They're generically called 'Rectangular IDC connectors'. There are other companies that make then, such as TE/AMP.

They come in different pin sizes and spacing and for different wires gauges so if you're replacing one you need to know that. Different brands might have different latching mechanisms between the plugs and sockets as well.

The tool I usually used was a T-handle, but I also used a pneumatic tool for large jobs. You would need to get the correct tool for whichever brand and size of connectors you have.

Comment: Excellent.  The name company Panduit was rebranded PANCON in 1997 according to TME's website.  In addition, some are called MTA as in MTA-100.  Here's a webpage:  https://www.tme.com/us/en-us/linecard/p,pancon_1161/